# How do I make my contributions in azure repo show in my GitHub heatmap

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops

I'm new to azure devops and while at work I was thinking if this was posible.

The company that I work for uses Azure and was kind enough to provide me with a Microsoft account using their domain (Enterprise Account), with it I can create Azure repos so I can save my work there. Also, I have a preexisting GitHub account with my personal email and I want to keep my streak of contributions going.

Problem is that I want to (somehow) make every push I make in the Azure repo appear in my personal GitHub heatmap, I just cant get my head around how to do it.

So far I have cloned and pushed changes to the Azure repo and, although Azure repo recognizes that the push was made from my personal GitHub account, my heatmap doesn't show any contribution. Both of the accounts (Enterprise and Personal account) are members of the Azure Project.

Answer (score 1):

The [GitHub article on contributions](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#about-your-contribution-graph) states that *"Your profile contributions graph is a record of contributions **you've made to repositories on GitHub.com**.*

That means that even though you are using a GitHub account in your Azure DevOps repo, you are not actually committing work to github.com and therefore the contribution is not recorded by GitHub's contribution system.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a Github Actions script that migrates your commits from azuredevops into github so they can appear on your github profile.

Check it out and let me know if you have any questions!

https://github.com/Raamyy/azuredevops-commits-migrator